# Getting FitNesse suite results in XML rather than HTML format

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am using [FitNesseRunner](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/test/fitnesse/junit/FitNesseRunnerTest.java)  to run my FitNesse TestSuite in Jenkins. Below is my FitNesseRunner:

```
@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@Suite("TestSuite")
@FitnesseDir(".")
@OutputDir("./build/fitnesse-results")
```

It generates HTML results in build/fitnesse-results directory. I want to generate XML results instead of HTML. How can I make that happen?

FYI: I need XML results to provide the XML file path to FitNesse plugin (Path to fitnesse xml results file) in Jenkins.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you must (or want to) use the Jenkins plugin? Running via FitNesseRunner already gives you results that Jenkins will pick up as test results, and the generated HTML report can be published using the 'HTML publisher'.

Comment: Hello Fried, FitNesseRunner does give results but it treats 1 table as 1 result. I wanted to have a result page for every test in the table. But using HTML publisher to display the HTML results does help. Navigating to passed/failed test is easier as well. Thanks for the advice.